# Magento ver. 1.9.3.0 No images in Admin and Unable to read the configuration file in Connect Manager

Tags: admin, image

I am unable to upload images via the admin upload button. It appears as though the upload is going to work but no image is attached to the product nor does it come into the images folder. The upload and browse buttons are there and available. Images on the front end are fine.

If I click to edit an old item (added before this problem) there is nothing in the images area. The image shows perfectly on the front end but nothing showing in the admin. These images are indeed in the correct media folder.

I have been searching, reading and editing pages and permissions for days now. I give up. I've gone through the first 4 pages of google and nothing has fixed the problem.

Can anyone offer any suggestions besides change the permissions?

Also, not sure if it is related, I am seeing an "Unable to read the configuration file" error when trying to use magentoconnect manager.

Comment: Had a friend do a search for a fix as well. He found something which had not come up in my searches. The Creare SEO extension needed a patch. I used this and the admin images problem is gone.

https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO/pull/78/files

Now to figure out the configuration file error.

Comment: version 1.9.3 got certain issues.